# JQuery Idle Time Issues in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-app

I have an interactive digital signage application that should allow for three minutes after each interaction before The mousemove and keypress functions are acting funky... Is "this" the correct call or should I use the body or a specific id/class?

```
var idleTime = 0;
$(".coverme").click(function () {
    //Increment the idle time counter every minute.
    var idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, 60000); // 1 minute

    //Zero the idle timer on mouse movement.
    $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
        idleTime = 0;
    });
    $(this).keypress(function (e) {
        idleTime = 0;
    });
});

function timerIncrement() {
    idleTime = idleTime + 1;
    if (idleTime > 3) { // in minutes
        $("#content").css('filter','blur(5px)');
        $("#helper").hide();
        $("#overlay").show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve with by changing the initial selector to document ready rather than element click.